# Block prompts when sites detect I'm using iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, safari

On many forum web sites, if you go to the site on an iPhone/iPod/iPad it prompts to install an app for the site.  But 90% of the time when I visit a forum site, it's because I'm following a search result; I never ever want to install the app. Is there some setting in iOS that disables this kind of prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sites are using JavaScript to detect Mobile Safari's user agent and displaying an alert.

You can disable JavaScript in Safari's settings but it's probably not worth the lost functionality.

Comment: On the plus side, there's probably some web proxy software that lets you change the user agent on a site-by-site basis. If your Wi-Fi network has a computer on it that's always on, you could set it up there and then just put the proxy in your Wi-Fi settings on the i-device.

Comment: I'm assuming the user agent would be detected on the server side.

Comment: You might be able to do something like that with [Glimmerblocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/).

Comment: on a jailbroken iPhone, you can download [User Agent Faker](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=3207) and change the user agent to another browser